# ZFS vs UFS for EMC Storage

Tags: zfs

I am new to ZFS and have been reading that EMC Storage may not like it.  I am building production servers that will be using Oracle 10g and Oracle 11g. Will I have any issues using ZFS or should I use UFS?  Any input is appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS prefers accessing the disks directly and doing all of the RAID itself, in software, getting you some nice things like being able to tell what drive is corrupting data if issues are detected during a hash check - but that leads you in a direction completely opposite of the EMC way, which is to handle all of the RAID in (expensive, redundant) hardware with (expensive, redundant) write caching, etc.

This is probably what you read about when looking into it - it's kinda a philosophical difference.

That said, you can still do ZFS in both ways; giving it direct access to all the disks (which the array can do) or giving it a RAID'd LUN and putting a ZFS pool on top of that.

Comment: And now that ZFS belongs to Oracle, it will make sure that it plays nicely with its Database products. So all in all, it is down to own preferences. Both will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle recommends that you utilize ASM. If that is not an option, then I would probably choose UFS since you are going to utilize EMC for redundancy and fault tolerance. Choosing ZFS on top of EMC's already provided redundancy seems to over complicate things. ...kiss